# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' occur while running the app

Tags: android-studio

I am a beginner in android studio. When I try to run the app on my mobile phone, android studio shows me this error:

> "execution failed for task ':app:mergedebugresources'. A failure
> occurred while executing
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable"

My build gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.newlogin2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    
    aaptOptions{
        cruncherEnabled = false
        useNewCruncher = false
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

Any one can help please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check your code if you follow some tutorials and then
go to
file -> invalidate caches/Restart

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried but it still doesn't work.(but the time building is faster)